# My accuracy does not change and giant loss

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I found some reports where the loss and accuracy does not change. But here the loss changes — *it is giant!* — and the accuracy does not change.

I've tried to increase the dataframe, decrease the dataframe, change the activation function. etc. But nothing changes the accuracy.

I have also tried to change the batch_size and the epochs. The curious thing is that when I use train_test_split, it works. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

```
Base = pd.read_csv(r"C:\...\Teste 6x3 Janela1.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")

x_treinamento = Base.iloc[Linha_i:Linha_f, 20:134]
y_treinamento = Base.iloc[Linha_i:Linha_f, 12]
x_teste = Base.iloc[Linha_i_Teste:Linha_f_Teste, 20:134]
y_teste = Base.iloc[Linha_i_Teste:Linha_f_Teste, 12]

rna = Sequential()
rna.add(Dense(units = 226, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', input_dim = 113))
rna.add(Dense(units = 226, activation = 'relu'))
rna.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
rna.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['binary_accuracy'])                     
rna.fit(x_treinamento, y_treinamento, batch_size = 2, epochs = 100)

Epoch 1/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -54259.0588 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 2/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -783880.1310 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 3/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -4232499.0056 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 4/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -13589123.4944 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 5/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -32081543.0112 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 6/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -63825447.9551 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
.
.
.
Epoch 96/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -240481326482.6966 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 97/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -246697877964.2247 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 98/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -253059365623.3708 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 99/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -259567427491.9550 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
Epoch 100/100
89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: -266072634862.7416 - binary_accuracy: 0.2472
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer here 'cause I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Try do randomize your train and test data, when you do not do that, the model can learn with the sequence of data and overfit or underfit. sklearn.train_test_split() can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found! I solved with:

```
ss = StandardScaler()
x_treinamento = ss.fit_transform(x_treinamento)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_treinamento)
y_treinamento = encoder.transform(y_treinamento)
```